# 3rd party api call with aws lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call `keepa api` within my `aws lambda` but the api is not getting called. The response is not getting printed.
But when I am running it on my `local machine`, its running fine and returning response.

*code from local machine :*

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        KeepaAPI api = new KeepaAPI("my-api-key");
        Request r = Request.getProductRequest(AmazonLocale.US, 90, null, "B001GZ6QEC");
        
        api.sendRequest(r)
                .done(result -> {
        
                                    System.out.println(result);
                                })
                .fail(failure -> System.out.println(failure));
                                }
}
```

*AWS lambda code*

```
public class App implements RequestHandler<String, Object>
{
    
    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
        System.out.println("welcome to lambda");
        
        KeepaAPI api = new KeepaAPI("my-api-key");
        Request r = Request.getProductRequest(AmazonLocale.US, 90, null, "B07W6SP4W1");
        
        System.out.println("before send request ");

        api.sendRequest(r)
                .done(result -> {       
                                    System.out.println(result);
                                })
                .fail(failure -> System.out.println(failure));
                
        System.out.println("after send request");

        return null;
        }
}
```

*Output : On the lambda console, I can only see welcome to lambda*

I am not sure whether we can call 3rd party apis from lambda. I researched a lot on this. Some said that may be my lambda is not getting internet connectivity but I tried to call instagram apis and it ran perfectly. Also my lambda is not in a VPC. I am not sure how to check that but in the image it shows "The function isn't connected to VPC"

[image: lambda]

Do I need an api gateway to call these apis? I am using official keepa java framework. I have assigned basic lambda role to this lambda. Do I need to assign some extra permissions to lambda role to call 3rd party api?

*lambda logs*
[image]

Comment: Let me get this straight - you are trying to communicate with a service that is external to AWS - like a 3rd party web service from within a Lambda function?  IS that correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using Keepa's api which is a 3rd party service within my lambda

Comment: "Do I need an api gateway to call these apis?" No, that's the opposite of what an API Gateway is for.

Comment: Yes, you can call external APIs from Lambda. No, you don't need API Gateway (which is for inbound API requests). No, it's not a VPC connectivity issue (because you can successfully call other external APIs). Add additional logs to your Lambda function, before sendRequest and after it (just to check that this is the actual code that is running), save and deploy the changed code, then re-run your test, then go to CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function. Does it help? If not, include the logs in your post (be sure to remove any sensitive info first).

Comment: Hey @jarmod Does my lambda role require some extra permissions to call 3rd party api? I have updated the answer with lambda logs.

Comment: There’s no such thing as permission to call a 3rd party API in IAM. You just need network connectivity to the relevant API’s endpoint and you need whatever credentials are required for the API. I’m not particularly familiar with Keepa API or async Java. Is there an option to await the deferred callback from sendRequest?

Comment: It worked by adding .waitSafely() after sendRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by adding waitSafely().

```
api.sendRequest(r)
                .done(result -> {       
                                    System.out.println(result);
                                })
                .fail(failure -> System.out.println(failure)).waitSafely();
```